# Release plugin - Maven/jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins-plugins, maven-release-plugin

I want to explore the possibility of relesing my code from develp branch to a new branch which also modifies the version in the pom files and commits it to git. 
I came across Jenkins Release Plugin and Maven Release Plugin.

What i read about Maven Release plugin does not give me confidence that it can be used only for the purpose i am looking. Moreover seems it has already been cited as being a poor plugin.

Can i use Jenkins release plugin for it? If not can you please suggest an alternative?

Comment: What do you mean by `relesing my code from develp branch to a new branch` ?

Comment: It means preparing for a potential release candidate for production deployment. Every new version of code is managed in a separate branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [release plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Release+Plugin): it is just a wrapper around build steps, in order to allow you to execute whatever task you need to build and tag a release.

The real issue is more around scripting your release steps (checkout of the develop branch, making a new branch, building, taging...): if you can script those (execute them as a script outside Jenkins) then you can integrated those commands in a Jenkins job, even a release one.